# can you helpe me to display the latest data on each group

Tags: mysqli

I have this datatables:

```
table1

id  category
-------------
1     a
2     b
3     c

table2

id heading category_id
----------------------
1   name      1
2   adddress  2
3   phone     3
4   email     1
```

I want to group this table and display the latest data for that the following query was I used:

```
SELECT news.id,news.image,news.heading,news.description,
        news.date,news.category_id,categories.category 
FROM `news` 
    INNER JOIN categories On news.category_id=categories.id 
group by category_id
```

But I didnt get the latest data that I entered.

Comment: What defines "the latest data"? Since you have no ORDER BY, results may be in arbitrary order...

Comment: Use `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`. There is no need to group them...

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table2 AS tb2 LEFT JOIN table1 AS tb1 ON tb2.category_id = tb1.id 
ORDER BY tb1.id 
GROUP BY tb2.category_id
```